# How to uninstall package and reinstall to factory/default settings?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, cache, tomboy

What I mean by this, is how do you reinstall a program to where it acts like it did the first time the program was ever opened?

**My scenario**

I Just did a fresh OS install, so I wanted to copy my my old tomboy notes from my usb stick to `/home/.local/share/tomboy` but apparently It doesn't work that way and now my tomboy notes opens very slowly, and my old notes don't show up in there.....I went back and deleted everything out of the`/home/.local/share/tomboy` but tomboy still opens very slowly.

I've tried `apt-get remove tomboy` and `apt-get install tomboy` but it still opens to it's old state and opens slowly still.

What I want to accomplish is to reinstall tomboy so that it opens up as it does on the very first open -- when it opens the app itself, and an additional note on how to use tomboy -- and opens up quickly too-- that's the main problem I'm trying to solve.

Is there an app cache somewhere that stores app settings? I tried to delete `/home/.local/share/tomboy` after removing tomboy in the package manager, but it doesn't seem to reset everything. Anyone know how I can reinstall tomboy to its factory original state?

Thanks

Comment: You probably want `sudo apt-get purge tomboy`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! You should have posted that as an answer so I can mark it as correct answer, but even so, it worked so thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `sudo apt-get purge tomboy` will "purge" the package, meaning it will remove it and all of its associated files. The command doesn't work for everything, but, as you said in the comments, it works for this.